Subscription handling in Stripe
As far as I understand, the webhook customer.subscription.updated fires off monthly by default. After one month, it isn't clear if the payment has gone through or not, subscription.status being set to trialing. It can take a few days for invoice.paid to fire off.
In the meantime, should an user get access to the subscription's benefits or not? I'm curious whether this is a common situation when implementing subscriptions and if it is up to the developer to decide whether to "optimistically" give the user premium access, or wait until the payment is sure to be successful

This is not really an integration question, and the approach will depend on your business needs and customer relationships. If you're accepting async payment methods then you need to decide on the risk/complexity of continued access vs temporary lockouts.

@NolanH not accepting async payments, but even with cards/paypal the "invoice.payment_successful" event gets fired ~2 days after customer.subscription.updated indicating a month has passed

This sounds like there is another issue causing this behaviour. Check the events/state transitions on your invoices. Most likely you have a webhook endpoint receiving invoice.created and failing to respond with a success/200 status. This will cause the invoice to remain as a draft for up to 72 hrs before timing out and finalizing regardless of the webhook delivery failure. See docs: https://docs.stripe.com/invoicing/integration/workflow-transitions#finalized

Based on the additional information in your comment reply above, it sounds like there is another issue causing this payment delay ehaviour. Check the events/state transitions on your invoices. Most likely, you have a webhook endpoint receiving invoice.created event and failing to respond with a success/200 status. This will cause the invoice to remain as a draft for up to 72 hrs before timing out and finalizing regardless of the webhook delivery failure.
You should investigate the failing webhook delivery, but you also have the option of forcing finalization (and therefore payment) by using the/finalize API.
See docs: https://docs.stripe.com/invoicing/integration/workflow-transitions#finalized
